# Set host from environment variable in HTTP request node

Tags: node-red

I have a node-red HTTP Request node.
I want to use as url, something like this:

> http://SERVER_HOST:SERVER_PORT/

How can I substitute `server_host` and `server_port` with their equivalent value from the environment?

I don't want to add another node just to set this url, if possible

I've tried:

```
${SERVER_HOST}
$(SERVER_HOST)
$env(SERVER_HOST)

${'SERVER_HOST'}
$('SERVER_HOST')
$env('SERVER_HOST')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only set the whole value from a single environment variable directly in nodes configuration.

So you have 2 options:

1. Set the whole URL as environment variable e.g. `$(SERVER_URL)`
2. Use a function node before hand to assemble the parts and set it as `msg.url` and then pass that into the HTTP-request node.